# How to combine multiple firebase docs to get a combined result?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my firebase db I have 3 collections:

```
Users
  {user_id}: {name: "John Smith"}

Items
  {item_id}: {value: 12345}

Actions
  {action_id}: {action: "example", user: {user_id}, items:{item_id}}
```

Basically, instead of storing the Users and Items under the Actions Collection, I just keep an ID. But now I need a list of all actions and this also needs info from the Users and Items Collection. How can I efficiently query firebase so I can get a result that looks like this:

```
{
    action: "example",
    user: {
       name: "John Smith"
    },
    item: {
       value: 1234
    }
}
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing in firebase or a similar database, basically, you are looking for a traditional join, which is no recommended thing to do in a NoSQL database.

If you want to do it in firebase, you will need:

1. Get the element you are looking for from your main collection *Actions* in this case.
2. Then you need to do another call to the Items collections where item_id == action.item_id.
3. Then assign in the actions["Item"] = item_gotten.

This is not a recommended use as I said, usually, when you are using a NoSQL Database you are expecting a denormalize structure, from your application you need to save the whole Item, in the Action JSON, and also in the Item. Yes, you will have duplicate data but this is fine for this kind of model. also you shouldn't expect too many changes in one specific object within your whole object key If you are managing a big set of changes you could be using the incorrect kind of DB.

For aggregation queries reference, you might check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation